# A bug in kendo grid in batch mode, passing two rows when deleting or updating one row

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-grid, crud

I'm using a Kendo grid version 14.1 for CRUD with Batch mode operations in a MVC web application, I noticed that when going in this scenario:

1. Press Delete to delete a row
2. Press Save to save data
3. If this row isn’t deleted for some validation rule
4. The grid refresh and re-fetch data from data source
5. The deleted row will be shown again in the grid (So far so good)
6. But when I delete another new row and debug the Delete Method in
   the controller
7. I see that the model view is holding the two rows (two rows are
   passed to the controller)
8. If I continue debugging the first row validation rule will be
   triggered and no rows will be deleted
9. Fortunately, If I pressed Cancel before deleting the second row then
   everything is ok and the model view will be initiated and only one
   row will be shown on debug.

So as a walk around to the issue, I want to call Cancel button from the error handler event of the grid (from JS) or any one can suggest a better solution to this issue

I've googled for the kendo grid cancel event with no luck

I tried this to register in cancel event from Kendo Widget for UI (I'm using kendo grid for MVC)
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.bind("cancel", grid_cancel);
No luck in this too

Comment: For your note I'm using a cutom template for the grid Toolbar